# How can I read very long string from Console and Parse to numbers in a reasonable way in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I would like to read a very long string from Console, and parse to intergers in C#. Is there any good way to do?

the input looks like:
202 203 204 .. 202

and it contains 1000 numbers. I need az array of integers form the input.

I know this example:

```
StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
while (true) {
    char ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
    sb.Append(ch);
    if (ch=='\n') {
        break;
    }
}
```

But is there any faster way? Maybe use Readline() to read to the space separator in a loop?

Thanks ahead

Comment: What do you mean _"any faster way"_? Is this performing too slow? But yes, you could perhaps use `ReadLine()`, have you tried to?

Comment: Are all of the numbers simply separated by a space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var array = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do with invalid entries.

```
var numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')
                               .Where(x => { int i; return int.TryParse(x, out i);})
                               .Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

This will just skip entries that are not ints

Answer (score 1):

Use following code :

```
var arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(p=>int.Parse(p) ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can give you what you want

```
List<int> inputs = new List<int>();
foreach(string o in inputText.Split(' '));//space character
{
    bool correct = false;
    //add some controls for the control if the input is correct integer
    ...
    if(correct)
        inputs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(o));
}
```